# jQuery: fadeOut() with html(), weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

while making a simple random quote machine (part of a coding course I'm attending), I ran into a problem while trying to fade out an element in my HTML, that should then add some new HTML in it and fade it in. Here's the code:

```
  $(".quote-text").fadeOut(function() {
     $(this).html("<p>" + quotes[currentQuoteNum] + "</p>").fadeIn();
  });
```

The `quotes[currentQuoteNum]` just refers to a list of quote strings I have. For some reason, neither the `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` functions do not animate correctly. The delay is there before my HTML is updated with a new quote, but the animation is not displayed. Now, if I remove the p element like so:

```
$(".quote-text").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).html(quotes[currentQuoteNum]).fadeIn();
});
```

Then it works and both the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations are played. I need to have the p element in there, because inside them I'm adding another two elements to create quotation marks around my quote using a special styling class. I omitted those for simplicity. I know there are other ways but I want to know why this is happening.

Obviously this has something to do with adding tags to my HTML, but I have not been able to find out what it is. Please explain?

Comment: what if you do it like `var myHTML = "<p>" + quotes[currentQuoteNum] + "</p>";  $(this).html(myHTML).fadeIn();` ? and check the console also

Comment: @Mi-Creativity it does not change anything, exactly the same. I'm using CodePen online editor btw, is it possible that its a bug in the editor?

Comment: What would `.quote-text` be? The [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/2xdczrx6/) IMO.

Comment: @MinusFour .quote-text refers to another p element

Comment: Animation is working fine, see this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5xj7v5st/1/, what exactly is not working for you ?

Comment: you can't put a paragraph inside a paragraph...

Comment: @ArnarYngvason changing it to a div makes no difference whatsoever

Comment: @11thdimension http://codepen.io/jonkur/pen/vLyjeO thats the codepen in question if you care to check it out...

Comment: @MinusFour the codepen I linked? Then its getting even wierder, probably something with my browser. The author part works for me too, but not the actual quote

Comment: It was chrome, tried it with firefox and works no problem. Not sure what's causing the Chrome bug though. But thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks fine to me, should not be an issue.
Here is a codepen and it works as it should
[Fade codepen](http://codepen.io/adibas03/pen/NxdNVo)

```
$(".quote-text").fadeOut(function() {
     $(this).html("<p>" + "Oh Good"+ "</p>").fadeIn();
  });
```

why not check the content of your variable.Probably its not well formatted

Comment: Yes, your code works fine, mine doesn't albeit being virtually similar. Something weird going on, thanks though.

Comment: Not sure why, but the problem only occured on Chrome. Code is indeed fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this change

```
$(".quote-text").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(this).text(quotes[currentQuoteNum]).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

I just removed the inner `<p>` tag and replaced `html()` with `text()`

Here's working code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMgWvR

Comment: Yes that works, but as I said in my original post I need to use html() and I need to insert tags. But the problem seems to not be in the code but elsewhere, possibly something with my Chrome browser as it works fine with firefox. Thanks though.